# How to know how long my smartphone is running

Tags: 5.0-lollipop

In Android Lollipop, I can only see the estimated time how long the device will be up.
But I want to know how long my device is already running - where can I find this information? (Can't (and dont want to) believe it was removed completely from Lollipop...)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Go to `Settings > About Phone > Status` and scroll to the end of the options. You'll see the up time.

Comment: This no longer works on the Pixel 3 

Answer (score 6):

Simply run the `uptime` command inside a terminal (eg. via `adb` or through *Terminal Emulator*).
You will get an output telling you how long the device is running for since the last boot.

Example output: `up time: 02:57:16, idle time 10:21:25, sleep time 00:00:000`

- `up time`: as you may have expected, it's the time since boot.
- `idle time`: I currently don't know much about where this time comes from/how it is generated; it seems to be the time it was idling in the past 12 hours.
- `sleep time`: seems to be broken, `00:00:000` is the time I get even though the phone was  asleep most of the time.

Comment: Thx for this suggestion. Is it correct that it's not possible to see the uptime at the device itself? I mean you can read it from the graph, but thats not really comfortable.

Comment: @user2345998 See Pramod's answer. It's a little bit deep in the settings but there is a way.